# How do I get past players blocking doorways?

Tags: the-division

In The Division, if someone stands in front of the door (or something like that) then I find it impossible to get past this guy.

How do I get past the trolls blocking doors? This is annoying in places with lots of people.

Comment: I haven't actually played the division, so if you people have a suggestion for my answer of if the video is wrong please edit it.

Comment: How do you find it impossible to pass through the door, if you have not actually tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I could not pass people blocking doors. There also have been queues in front of some npcs you needed to talk to at the launch of the game. This sould not happen now, as the big wave is gone.

Only way to get around this harrassment by now is to tp to another safe house und exit from there. Maybe this will be changed in future.

Answer (score 3):

Just walk into the players blocking the door way for a few seconds, you will phase through them after roughly 3 seconds of running straight into them.